# Convert to a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

Describe a recursive function that determines the number of variables
a sign in a non-zero array.
I did it in a non-recursive one, but I need it in a recursive one.

```
int recur_change_sign(int* arr, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] < 0 && arr[i + 1] >= 0) || (arr[i] >= 0 && arr[i + 1] < 0)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it very easily like this:

```
int recur_change_sign(int* arr, int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 0;
    return ((arr[0] < 0 && arr[1] >= 0) || (arr[0] >= 0 && arr[1] < 0)) + recur_change_sign(arr + 1, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this code works?

Comment: The recursive function must have break condition, so the first line is the break condition line.  If n is same or lower than 1, then the function must return with 0. Otherwise the return value will be the second line. Perhaps you can prove very easily about the second.

Comment: I understood the first one, thank you, but can you please also tell me what happens in the second return?

Comment: In the second? What does mean recur_change_sing(arr+1, n-1)? It's the result of arr[1],arr[2]....,arr[n-1]. So the main function return value will be func(arr[0],arr[1])+recur_change_sign(arr+1,n-1). Here func(arr[0], arr[1])= ((arr[0] < 0 && arr[1] >= 0) || (arr[0] >= 0 && arr[1] < 0));

Comment: A tail-recursive version would be better.

Comment: @real_fan Is it possible to do this with {throw} exception output when the array size is <= 1?

Answer (score 0):

It can also be realized by removing it from the tail.

```
int recur_change_sign(int* arr, int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 0;
    return ((arr[n-2] < 0 && arr[n-1] >= 0) || (arr[n-2] >= 0 && arr[n-1] < 0)) + recur_change_sign(arr, n - 1);
}
```